# MVVM not binding after initial value has been entered

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm facing an odd issue with my WPF (MVVM) project.

I have a few controls which bind to the properties in the ViewModel. INotifyPropertyChanged is configured, everything (initially works). I type in some values into my controls and I click a button. I can see, by stepping through the code, all the property values are what they should be. So far, it is text book.

Now I notice the issue. After I click the button, some logic is performed, such as saving these values to a database. I can then edit the control values and then save to the database again. The properties at this point to do not update.

Binding clearly works, because the output shows no binding errors and when I click the Save button, the properties are correct. However, after I click the save button, and then change the property values, the properties are not updatdd. I cannot fathom why this is the case.

As a trial, I added the PropertyChanged to the update source trigger and this seems to fix the issue, however, I've never had to do this before. Any ideas what could be wrong?

I don't believe the answer is 2 way binding (I am happy to be wrong) because it binds!

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding DataSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row ="1" Grid.Column="2" />
```

Where as normally I would use

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding DataSource}" Grid.Row ="1" Grid.Column="2" />
```

Comment: Without the `UpdateSourceTrigger`, the value is committed only after the `TextBox` looses focus. Does that affect your use case? Also, if the Text is loaded from the database, you should use `TwoWay` binding mode.

Comment: Can you please let us know after what kind of change, Value update got failed?

Comment: @helb, sorry, I didn't mention, I had already done tried TwoWay out of hacking - it made no difference. Besides, it is only 1 way binding (from my View to my ViewModel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UpdateSourceTrigger property determines the time, when the binding has to be updated. The default value for this property is LostFocus. So by default, after you type something and move the focus out, the binding will update. If you set the property value to PropertyChanged, binding will update immediately once you entered the value in text box.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx

In your case, the binding is updated on button click, since focus transferred to Button from textbox. Once the UpdateSourceTrigger set to PropertyChanged, the binding will update on every text change.

Comment: I'm lost, there is an option for Default, Explicity, LostFocus and PropertyChanged? If the default is LostFocus, what is the Default for? I also know how UpdateSourceTrigger works, hence using both of these in my example, my question is why it is needed. When I click the button, surely it means the TextBox has lost focus?

Comment: @Dave The "default" depends on the DependencyProperty, similar to the binding mode. See the documentation for UpdateSourceTrigger.Default: "The default UpdateSourceTrigger value of the binding target property. The default value for most dependency properties is PropertyChanged, while the Text property has a default value of LostFocus."

Comment: @helb, thanks for this, but, when I click on a button, surely the TextBlock's LostProperty is executed before the 'onclick' of the button?

Comment: @Dave Don't make assumptions on the order of events fired in WPF. This led to tears on my side a few times already...

Comment: Tonight I am by a PC - I need to do some testing really. Very interesting comment, very very interesting comment! Thank you @helb

Comment: @Dave let me know if you find something while debugging ;-)